# Tchebychev's polynomial and vector spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

This polynomial is defined by:
$T_n(x)=cos(narccos(x)) \forall x \in [-1,1]$
I could prove a recurrence relation:
$T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$
But i couldn't deduce from this that Tn is a polynomial of degree n
Please make it an obvious explanation.

Answer (score 0):

By induction:
$T_0(x)=1$ $T_1(x)=x$ that are polynom

Thus if we assume that $T_n$ and $T_{n-1}$ are polynomial by your relation $T_{n+1}$ is a polynom and therefore $\forall n\ T_n$ is a polynom